# how to drag and drop the text into the rounded rectangle in html5

Tags: html, css, rounded-corners

I am new to HTML5. I have created a rounded rectangle in HTML5. This is the code for rectangle.

```
<div style="position:absolute; width:148px; height:44px; left:255px; -webkit-border-radius: 22px;-moz-border-radius: 22px;border-radius: 22px; border:2px solid #FFFFFF; background-color:#4D0C00;  top: 98px;"> </div>
```

What i need to do is i have to show series of words above that rectangle. Among the words i have to drag one word and drop it in the rounded rect. If I select some other word and drop, then the old word has to return to its original place. Can anyone help me in this.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: I had created the rounded rect buttons. Now i am trying to display the words in carosel format. After that i want the drag and drop